# jest coverage - /* istanbul ignore next */ - not working

Tags: javascript, jestjs, istanbul, test-coverage

Wanted this part of the code to be ignored in jest coverage

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
async middleware(
    req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>,
    _res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>,
    next: NextFunction
) {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    await validate({ email, password })

    next()
}
```

I tried with `/* istanbul ignore next */` but it doesn't seem to work

[coverage result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDgtW.png)

Comment: Have you tried to put the /* Istanbul ignore next */ comment next to the function name, right before the parameters?

Comment: I have the same problem. I put the /* Istanbul ignore next */. I put it in several positions, but it´s not working.  I am using: "nyc": "^15.1.0" and  "ts-jest": "^29.0.5", "jest": "^29.5.0", "ts-jest": "^29.0.5".

I put the comment (before/after function name, before/after function parameters) but the ```/* Istanbul ignore next */ ``` not working in any position.